# How to install php_curl in ubuntu 16.04 server?

Tags: php, php7

I am trying to install php curl in ubuntu. but couldn't do it. I got the below error while installing the package.

[image: error image]

My php version is 7.0
and  ubuntu version is 16.04. Kindly check and guide to me...

Comment: Have you ran `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: yes, i have tried that also.. that is working fine. but couldn't install the php curl package..

Comment: Have you ran `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: yes, i have run this command also.. there after i also restart the apache server..

Comment: And  after those the output is still the same?

Comment: Is deb `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main` enabled in uour /etc/apt/sources.list?